# Querying mysql with a bridge table

Tags: mysql

I have a database scheme like this:

[image]

All I want is to query data from these tables where the one in the middle is a bridgetable.

I want to write a query to get Details from WrapupCodes table for all the WrapupIds that exists in  Bridgetable for the same contactId as in CallDetails table.

e.g:

[image]

Similarly this is the table I want to get details from

[image]

And here is the main table.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very basic SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM WrapupCodes w
INNER JOIN Contact_Wrapup c ON c.WrapupID = w.WrapupID
INNER JOIN CallDetail d on d.ContactID = c.ContactID
```